# Regex Capture Within First Paragraph Only

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need a regex expression to capture everything preceding a colon within the first paragraph only of a multi-paragraph string.

Input1:

> Rochester: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
>   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur.
>
> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
>   officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Output1:

> Rochester

Everything that precedes the colon in the first paragraph.

Input2:

> Rochester Hills: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
>   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur.
>
> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
>   officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Output2:

> Rochester Hills

Everything that precedes the colon in the first paragraph.

Input3:

> Rochester Hills: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
>   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur.
>
> Sisters: sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
>   officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Output3:

> Rochester Hills

Only that which precedes the colon in the first paragraph, completely ignoring the string that precedes the colon in a later paragraph.

Input4:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
>   nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
>   pariatur.
>
> Sisters: sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
>   officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Output 4: Nothing should be captured as a colon does not appear in the first paragraph.

Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry that I forgot about my previous efforts. I had been working with:

```
(?=.*:[ ]).*?(?=[:][ ])
```

This works for another instance where the colon never appears in later paragraphs. But for this case I did not understand how I could modify it to only look within the first paragraph.

Comment: What programming environment? Most regex tools are terrible with new lines...

Comment: @CommuSoft This is for a regex expression within the web scraping software Mozenda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get your expected results...

```
^[^\n\r]+(?=:)
```

starts with any amount of anything up until a newline/return if followed by a colon. tested this gives desired results for all of your examples

Comment: Why are `\n\r` not allowed?

Comment: paragraphs are separated by a blank line, thus `\n\n`. A new line is allowed in a paragraph.